# Use wstool but keep git directories organized under a custom structure

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, update, git, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Imagine I have the following structure in my directory:

```
ros_ws
|__src
       |.rosinstall
       |__robots
                |__baxter
                     |__baxter.rosinstall
                     |__baxter_sdk
                     |__.git
                      ...
                |__sawyer
                     |__sawyer.rosinstall
                     |__sawyer_sdk
                     |__.git
```

Is there a way to call wstool update locally or globally to update git repos but keep them in my pre-established structure. Currently when I do wstool update it want to place updated git repo folders directly under ros_ws/src.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320373/use-wstool-but-keep-git-directories-organized-under-a-custom-structure/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2019-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but the `.rosinstall` format supports specifying a destination for clones/checkouts of repositories with the `local-name` property.

The [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosinstall_file_format.html) on the file format describes it as:

> Inside every top level dictionary there is one required key, `local-name` this represents the path where to install files. It will support both workspace relative paths as well as absolute paths.

So if you want to keep things in a different directory than directly in your source space, you could do that by setting `local-name` to something like:

```
some_dir/other_dir/baxter/..
```

Each entry has its own `local-name` key, so each repository can be placed in a different directory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on 2019-04-10**:
Great!!! Thanks for that tip!